# Cycle Count Profiling on ARM DS-5 Simulator

Tags: arm, simulator, cortex-a8, ds-5

I am trying to use a profiler on DS-5 Simulator. I dont want to attach any boards at this time and hence I believe I cannot use the Streamline Analyzer.

My question is how can I see code coverage and cycle count usage on DS-5 Simulator (Cortex A8) on Windows in Eclipse environment.

Thanks

Comment: You mean attaching a board to Simulator? It says simulator can boot up Linux, then you should be able to use Streamline. That's not enough?

Comment: no I am using no board. Just the RTSM Simulator

Comment: Talked to ARM support regarding this. It looks like DS-5 doesnt support profiler on Simulator as RVDS 4.1 use to. For profiling with DS-5, one has to use Streamline with a board.

Comment: but simulator can boot up like a board, then it should be usable.

Answer (score 1):

The simulators that ARM provides are called [Fast Models](http://ds.arm.com/ds-5/model/) (or fixed virtual platforms, depending on the degree of flexibility you want). They are not designed to be cycle accurate, but are instead instruction accurate. Basically, they give you a "programmer's view" of a system.

For this reason, running Streamline on a model in order to optimize an application or system wouldn't give you a realistic performance profile.

Hope this helps!